# python 3.5 access denied

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to open a text file using python I have looked on stack overflow and I know how to open the file but the access is denied, I have been in the file properties and I have full access over the file and the program... here is my code :

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call(['"C:\\Users\\Edvin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\Notepad.lnk"', 
'C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\Test.txt'])
```

and here is the error: `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`how do you grant access??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run a `.lnk` file, which is actually a binary file containing a path to the real executable. While double clicking on the shortcut works for the end user, such shortcuts are opaque to other programs like Python. **`.lnk` files cannot be run like `.exe` files.** You should directly start `notepad.exe`, which is located either in `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` or `C:\Windows\notepad.exe`.